# Any legal challenges for a wife in same-sex couple to adopt a child?

Tags: united-states, family-law, adoption

Situation: a **married** same sex lesbian couple chooses to have a child, by using a sperm donor (this is USA, state is unknown for sure but let's say PA or NY).

From what I understand, the standard advice for the spouse who is not the birth mother, is to adopt the child, to be considered fully-rightsed parent legally.

**The question is, are there any challenges for such an adoption, from the fact that this is a lesbian female spouse and there was a sperm donor in the picture? If so, what can the challenges be, and what can be done to alleviate them to ensure smooth adoption?**

Assume that the donor is not named on birth certificat as a father, and does not intend to be in the picture at all (so, there won't be a legal challenge for adoption originating from the donor).

(a small sub-question: if the state allows naming a female lesbian partner as a parent on birth certificate, would such a naming help with adoption or have no effect compared to leaving the birth certificate with a mother only and unlisted father?)

Comment: Why is their sexual orientation relevant?

Comment: @Rick FWIW same sex marriage status is relevant under the laws of many states at least based upon statutes on the books and last controlled cases.